# href/button click overrules the next step and executes the action without waiting for user input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Lengthy (sorry) description of the problem: I have a table that has user information per row and a few links to send for example a reminder email to do a questionnaire or an invitation to do so.

Clicking on any of the links/buttons the **first time** opens a (jquery) dialog box displaying a form with the email content, subject line and email address plus a few buttons: Send, Cancel etc - this is to make sure that the content is correct, it's the right person etc.

When I select "Send Reminder" the form does what it should do, send the email to the person in that row.

Clicking on another link it automatically sends the email not waiting for me to press any of the buttons **BUT** it sends as content the (ajax) success message that was displayed in the email window.

I read the code over and over and I cannot figure out why this happens, I need your help, please!

The table is based upon php, tablesorter, jquery and javascript and one row would look like this (There are two href and button doing the same, I tried both - all doing the same thing incorrectly)

```
<tr class="odd">
 <td>jobst4</td>
 <td>exmpl4@domain.com</td>
 <td><a href="javascript://" onclick="SendEmail('remind','jobst4');return false;" title="Send email to 'jobst4' with type 'remind'">Send</a><input role="button" class="button button_remind ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="Send" onclick="SendEmail('remind','jobst4');return false;" type="button"></td>
</tr>
```

The row above is repeated with different values, the passed parms to SendEmail will setup what's displayed in the email jquery dialo box.

The dialog box in a php script is created like so:

```
...
$RetVal .= "<div id=\"dialog\"  title=\"Message Dialog Box\" style=\"display:none;z-index:3000;\"></div>";
...
echo $RetVal;
...
```

The Form that shows up in the jquery dialog box:

```
  ...
  $RetVal  = "Edit the content of the email message and press submit.";
  $RetVal .= "<hr>";
  $RetVal .= "<form id=\"MailForm\" name=\"MailForm\" method=\"POST\" \">";
  $RetVal .= "<table style='width:800px;'>";
  $RetVal .= "<tr><td align=right>FROM:</td><td><input size=80 type=text name=\"from\" value=\"".$EmailFrom."\"></td></tr>";
  $RetVal .= "<tr><td align=right>TO:</td><td><input size=80 type=text name=\"address\" value=\"".$userData['firstname']." ".$userData['lastname']." <".$userData['email'].">\"></td></tr>";
  $RetVal .= "<tr><td align=right>CC:</td><td><input size=80 type=text name=\"cc\" value=\"\"></td></tr>";
  $RetVal .= "<tr><td align=right>BCC:</td><td><input size=80 type=text name=\"bcc\" value=\"".$EmailBcc."\"></td></tr>";
  $RetVal .= "<tr><td align=right>SUBJECT:</td><td><input size = 100 type=text name=\"subject\" value=\"".$subject."\"></td></tr>";
  $RetVal .= "<tr><td colspan=2><textarea id='mailbody' name='mailbody'>".$content."</textarea></td></tr>";
  $RetVal .= "<tr><td colspan=2>";
  $RetVal .= "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Email\" onClick=\"SendEmail();jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');return false;\"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" value=\"Close Me\" onClick=\"jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');return false
;\">";
  $RetVal .= "</td></tr>";
  $RetVal .= "</table></form>";
  ...
  echo $RetVal;
```

The javascript that is executed when clicking link/button:

```
$RetVal .= "<script language=\"javascript\">
function SendEmail()
{
 console.log('function SendEmail');
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'THE_SCRIPT_THAT_DOES_THE_MAILING.php',
  data: $('#MailForm').serialize(),
  success: function(data)
  {
   console.log('success1');
   if(data.status=='success')
   {
    console.log('success2');
    console.log(data.content);
    $('#mailbody').html(data.content);
   }
   else
   {
    console.log('darn!');
    $('#mailbody').html('<h1>ERROR</h1>'+data.content);
   }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR,exception)
  {
    console.log('There was an error executing this(2): '+jqXHR.status+' '+jqXHR.responseText+' - '+exception);
  }
 });
}
</script>
";
```

Even pressing the (bloody) close will send the email (again).

What did I do wrong or do not see?

Help!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

1. remove onclick event from .
2. put href="javascript:SendEmail('remind','jobst4');" in .

Comment: Sorry - did not make a difference - thanks for trying.

Comment: I have even tried with different return values for the javascript functions, different ID's for everything ... nothing helps.